# In mongodb, how to get 10 documents with id lesser than 100 but not from 1 to 10 instead from 90 to 99

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection with an index on the id field in the ascending order.

How to get 10 documents from the collection whose id is lesser than say 100 but not the first 10 instead the last ten below 100.

The below query gives me data from 1 to 10.

```
db.products.find({id:{$lt:100}}).limit(10)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
db.products.find({id:{$lt:100}}).sort({"id":-1}).limit(10)
```

Comment: Since i already have an index on the id field in ascending order, can i avoid sort operation in your query to get the desired result.

Comment: you will have to use sort because your data is in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

`db.products.find({id:{$lt:100}}).skip(90)`

Comment: What if the id element doesn't have continuous sequence. In that case skipping data wont work

Comment: Fair point. @Undefined_variable's answer is the better one. [If an ascending or a descending index is on a single field, the sort operation on the field can be in either direction.](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/)

Comment: Even if they were continuous, you'd also need to add a `sort` for this to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also  try

```
db.products.find({$and:[{id:{$lt:100}},{id:{$gte:90}}]}).limit(10);
```

Which will return maximum of 10 docs from the 'id' range of 90-99.

Comment: As i pointed out earlier in one of the comments, the id doesn't always have to be contiguous

Comment: I was referring to the title of your question - you wanted 10 docs from 90 to 99, and that's what the query returns...

Comment: I understand. Given that, [Undefined_variable](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2539103/undefined-variable)'s answer is 100% correct and appropriate.